# Custom directive not working in dynamically loaded component - Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11

I have a custom attribute directive named **CrispEdgeDirective**. It's is not getting rendered in **contact component** which is dynamically loaded from **intro component**.

I could not see the **crisp-edge** CSS class is added to the img tag of the contact component.

Can someone provide your suggestions to resolve this issue?

[image]

**intro-component.html**

```
<ng-template #contactContainer></ng-template>
<ng-container>
 <div>
    <button appButton (click)="showContact()">Contact</button>
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

**intro.component.ts**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-intro',
 templateUrl: './intro.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./intro.component.css']
})
export class IntroComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

 @ViewChild("contactContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef })
 public contactContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;
 
 showContact(){
  let contactComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
                              .resolveComponentFactory(ContactComponent);
  let contactComponent = this.contactContainerRef.createComponent(contactComponentFactory).instance;
  this.contactCloseSub = contactComponent.close.subscribe(() =>{
  this.contactContainerRef.clear();
   })
  }
}
```

**contact.component.html**

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/30px.png" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="contact_brand" appCrispEdge>
 </div>
</div>
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-contact",
  templateUrl: "./contact.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
 })
export class ContactComponent{ }
```

**crisp-edge.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCrispEdge]'
})
export class CrispEdgeDirective implements OnInit{

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

ngOnInit(): void{
  this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'crisp-edges');
 }
}
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { CrispEdgeDirective } from './../directives/crisp-edge.directive';
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CrispEdgeDirective,
 ],
exports: [
    CrispEdgeDirective
 ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**app-home.module.ts**

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';
import { AppHomeRoutingModule } from './app-home-routing.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IntroComponent } from '../components/intro/intro.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
 ],
exports: [],
 declarations: [
    IntroComponent
 ]
})
export class AppHomeModule{ }
```

Comment: It is not recommended to manipulate the DOM directly... I think you can use a component for this, with an input or content projection.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: @AravindP Can you please create a stackblitz demo for it?

Comment: @AravindP how did you fixed this issue. I am also facing same. Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I think you'll probably be able to solve it by adding `contactComponent.detectChanges()`, which is a method on the object returned from `contactContainerRef.createComponent()`